# how to wait for promise resolve in array.map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I want to upload photos to firebase storage.

In the state of React component I have array with photos. Photos are files that user browse through file input. Photos has property `.needUpload` to `true`, if file need to upload to storage.

Here is upload function:

```js
uploadPhotos = () => {
    let photosToSave = []
    if (this.state.photos.length) {
      photosToSave = this.state.photos
        .filter(photo => photo.needUpload && true)
        .map(photo => {
          const extensionPattern = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/
          const fileName = photo.value.name
          const fileExtension = extensionPattern.exec(fileName)[1]
          const newFileName = new Date().getTime()
          const fileLocation = storageRef.child('estateObjects/' + newFileName + '.' + fileExtension)

          return new Promise(resolve => {
            fileLocation.put(photo.value).on(
              firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
              snapshot => {
                //let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
              },
              null,
              () => {
                fileLocation.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                  resolve({ url: url, file: newFileName + '.' + fileExtension })
                })
              }
            )
          })
        })
      return Promise.all(photosToSave).then(response => {
        return response
      })
    } else return Promise.all(photosToSave).then(response => [])
  }
```

The main problem is that when upload starts, it (patiently) waiting, I guess for upload first 2-3 files, then in 'resolve' array I'm getting duplicated array elements. So something working wrong, but I cant understand what...

**maybe problem is with new file name?? When file renames new Date.getTime() returns same time for few files, cause they where uploaded at the same time?**

[image]

Comment: yes, the map loop runs very quickly, so the time won't change

Comment: So what's the best way to rename file with unique name?

Comment: new Date().getTime() is giving same time, it's running quickly

Comment: you could `.map((photo, index) =>` and use the `index` to ensure unique filenames

Comment: `const newFileName = \`${new Date().getTime()}_${index}\`;`

Comment: Oh. so simply add to new File name index at the end:) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the map loop runs very quickly, so the time won't change between iterations

So, I suggest you use the `index` to guarantee filename uniqueness

```js
uploadPhotos = () => {
  let photosToSave = [];

  if (this.state.photos.length) {
    photosToSave = this.state.photos.filter(photo => photo.needUpload && true).map((photo, index) => {
      const extensionPattern = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
      const fileName = photo.value.name;
      const fileExtension = extensionPattern.exec(fileName)[1];
      const newFileName = `${new Date().getTime()}_${index}`;
      const fileLocation = storageRef.child('estateObjects/' + newFileName + '.' + fileExtension);
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        fileLocation.put(photo.value).on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, snapshot => {//let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        }, null, () => {
          fileLocation.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            resolve({
              url: url,
              file: newFileName + '.' + fileExtension
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(photosToSave).then(response => {
      return response;
    });
  } else return Promise.all(photosToSave).then(response => []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative to add a synchronous method on newFileName can work.

```
var time = ''; //Global variable
```

```
function getTime() {
   if(new Date().getTime() === time){return getTime()}
   else time = new Date().getTime();
   return time;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example on how iteration over an array with map get execute faster than milliseconds between clock change.

```
 [...Array(7).keys()].map(v=> console.log(new Date().getTime()))
```

For 7 items it mostly creates only one output, but sometimes it produce 2 different values like this:

```
VM676:2 1572510011727
VM676:5 1572510011728
```

One way to solve this is by creating uniqe is's using [uuid library,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) It will produce unique filenames

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
uuidv1(); // ⇨ '2c5ea4c0-4067-11e9-8bad-9b1deb4d3b7d'
```